# Problems with RDP in WIndows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have a vps that runs Windows XP. I remote desktop connect to my vps and I close it but when I reconnect again it tells me to disconnect the current user so It doesn't use the existing session. But I want to use that existing session I don't want it to force discount the user. How can I fix this? in windows server 2003 this problem doesn't occur but in XP it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use a console connection from the RUN menu.

If using rdp from win xp it would be...

```
"mstsc /v=computername /console"
```

If running from vista and up in think you need to use...

```
"mstsc /v=computernamehere /admin"
```